# Why are layout parameters not supported in JavaFX CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx-2, javafx

I've been coding a GUI in JavaFX and have gotten to styling it with CSS. However, I came to learn that there is no support for setting layout parameters such as min-width, pref-width, etc. (These show up in the docs but are filed under WebView only.) Instead of getting a nicely sized `TextField`, I have one that's spread across the entire screen.

Now I know the solution is to just go hardcode these layout parameters in Java (the documentation pointed me to JavaFX Script but that's been dead since 2009), but I'm wondering why I have to do this? What's the point? I'm not a CSS pro, but it seems like bad design to only abstract *some* of your styling. Now it's in two places? Are there any plans to change this?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you request has been implemented in [Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/).

See [RT-20906 Support setting min/pref/max sizes via css](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20906).

It could be argued that layout and styling a separate things and JavaFX already has FXML as a declarative layout system, so perhaps the need for layout parameters in CSS is slightly less if you are using SceneBuilder and FXML for your layout (at least that is what my experience with the technology has lead me to believe).